# break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop

Tags: bash, ssh

Troubleshooting a error output at the end of a script.

This...

```
# We now request that the user restarts their server...
read -e -p "Restart your server now to complete the install (y/n)? " rsn
    case $rsn in
        [Yy]* ) break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;
    esac
done
```

Produces...

```
/dev/fd/63: line 446: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
/dev/fd/63: line 449: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/dev/fd/63: line 449: `done'
```

Any ideas on an alternate to `break;;` in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do nothing :) That is, either use for example `true` or `:` instead of `break` or remove the line altogether.

A better solution would be to actually use a `while` loop:

```
while true
do
    [your code]
done
```

This way the `break` does what you want, and you fix a bug: What happens if `rsn` *doesn't* start with `[YyNn]`?

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation of the subject. Tossed `while true; do` in there and everything runs smooth.